# ExpandableListView change into ListView

Tags: android, listview

In my Android-App I have an ExpandableListView. I want to change it into an normal ListView. Is it posible without changing the complete code?

Here is the code from the adapter class: 
The code is without all imports, because there are many imports.

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private Map<String, List<BizDriveNotification>> bizCollections;
    private List<String> biz;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> biz,     Map<String, List<BizDriveNotification>> bizCollections) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bizCollections = bizCollections;
        this.biz = biz;
    }   



    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return bizCollections.get(biz.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,  boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final BizDriveNotification note = (BizDriveNotification) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }




        ImageView symbol = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgNotification);
        String checkNotification;        
        checkNotification = note.type.toString();
        if (checkNotification.equals("notiz")){
            //setz als Symbol das BizDrive-Icon für Notiz
            symbol.setImageResource(R.drawable.notiz);
            } else if (checkNotification.equals("aufgabe")){
                //setz als Symbol das BizDrive-Icon für Auffgaben
                symbol.setImageResource(R.drawable.aufgabe);
                }else if (checkNotification.equals("kalendertermin")){
                    //setz als Symbol das BizDrive-Icon für Kalender
                    symbol.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalender);
                }




        TextView timeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nfDateTime);
        if (note.time == null ){
            timeDate.setText("");
            }else{
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy\nHH:mm");
                timeDate.setTextSize(8);
                timeDate.setText(simpleDateFormat2.format(note.time) + " Uhr");
                }      



        //baut den Titel zusammen
        TextView titel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nfHeader);
        titel.setText(note.title);
        titel.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        titel.setTextSize(16);

        //baut den Notification-Inhalt zusammen
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nfContent);
        description.setText(note.description);

        //setzt den Ersteller
        TextView creator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nfCreator);
        creator.setTextSize(8);
        creator.setText("Ersteller: " + note.creator);

//      //setzt das Datum
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nfCreationDate);
        //Datum in dd.MM.yyyy Format umwandeln und in die Liste eintragen
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        date.setTextSize(8);
        date.setText("erstellt am: " + simpleDateFormat.format(note.date));

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return bizCollections.get(biz.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return biz.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return biz.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }
    //Baut den Titel ListView Punkte zusammen
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.head);       
        item.setText(title);

        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {        
        return true;
    }


//    //aus der ListView eine XML Datei erzeugen und speichern
    public void persistListView(){      
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput("notifications.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            //Wurzelelement
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("notifications");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);           

            for (String singleKey : bizCollections.keySet()) {
                for(BizDriveNotification noti: bizCollections.get(singleKey)){
                    // Knotenpunkt notification
                    Element note = doc.createElement("notification");
                    rootElement.appendChild(note);           
                    // Knotenpunkt id
                    Element id = doc.createElement("id");
                    id.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(noti.id)));
                    note.appendChild(id);            
                    // Knotenpunkt title 
                    Element title = doc.createElement("title");
                    title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(noti.title));
                    note.appendChild(title);             
                    // Knotenpunkt description 
                    Element description = doc.createElement("description");
                    description.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(noti.description));
                    note.appendChild(description);           
                    // Knotenpunkt type 
                    Element type = doc.createElement("type");
                    type.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(noti.type));;
                    note.appendChild(type);
                      //Knotenpunkt creator 
                    Element creator = doc.createElement("creator");
                    creator.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(noti.creator));
                    note.appendChild(creator);
                    //Knotenpunkt time 
                    Element time = doc.createElement("time");
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                    if (noti.time != null){
                        time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(simpleDateFormat2.format(noti.time).toString()));
                        note.appendChild(time);
                    }
                    else{
                        time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(""));
                        note.appendChild(time);
                        }                       
                    // Knotenpunkt date 
                    Element date = doc.createElement("date");
                     SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(simpleDateFormat.format(noti.date).toString()));
                    note.appendChild(date);                                  
                }
            }           

            // Inhalt in xml Datei schreiben
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
            String newFileXml = sw.toString();      
                try {
                     //xml Datei speichern
                    OutputStreamWriter wrt = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
                    try {
                        wrt.write(newFileXml);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally{
                    if (wrt != null){
                        wrt.close();
                        }
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }     
          } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
          } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use your code. Need changes.

Comment: You'll have to change only the adapter and any type declaration if it is well designed. SHow your code.

Comment: Here ist the complete code of the adapter